# In Spring, How to Define Two Beans, with Same Name and Different Class

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, profile

I have a java project, using Spring. I have defined three classes: BaseClass, SubClass1 and SubClass2. Two SubClassx both extend BaseClass.
Now, I need to define two beans, one is in a specific profile:

```
<bean id="newBean" class="SubClass1">
```

and

```
<beans profile="xxx">
    <bean id="newBean" class="SubClass2">
</beans>
```

they are in different xml files. I use lombok to inject SubClass2 newBean in a Class:

```
public class WarmUpAgent extends WarmUpAgent {
    @Setter(onMethod = @__(@Required))
    private SubClass2 subClass2;
...

<bean id="warmUpAgent" class="WarmUpAgent">
    <property name="subClass2" ref="newBean" />
</bean>
```

But when I run the project with profile "xxx", it throws:

```
IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [SubClass1] to required type [SubClass2] for property 'subClass2'
```

It seems that fail to overwrite bean newBean with SubClass2, even though I have activated profile "xxx". Is there any way to use profile, to define two beans, with same name and different class?

Thank you very much.

========================================================================

I put

```
<bean id="newBean" class="SubClass1">
```

and

```
<beans profile="xxx">
    <bean id="newBean" class="SubClass2">
</beans>
```

in one xml file, and it works. But I'd like to separate them into two xml files, according to the project organization. Any solutions to implement this?

Comment: You keep saying same name, but you are using same id not name!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I also tried using name, it doesn't work as well.

Comment: can you show your 2 xml files

Answer (score 1):

Try restricting the first bean to the default profile

```
<beans profile="default">
  <bean id="newBean" class="SubClass1">
</beans>
<beans profile="xxx">
   <bean id="newBean" class="SubClass2">
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ***same name*** instead of id.

```
<bean name="newBean" class="SubClass1">
<beans profile="xxx">
    <bean name="newBean" class="SubClass2">
</beans>
```